# How to use Particle Swarm Optimization for finding optimal bandwidth with cross-validation?

Tags: machine-learning, matlab, kernel-smoothing

I want to use Particle Swarm Optimization (PSO)for finding optimal smoothing parameters of a kernel density estimation problem. Initially I tried to find the same using grid search method,but the Matlab code is taking too long to produce results. Even after reading a lot on PSO, I am still not clear on how to apply it. Can anybody help me understand or  refer me to some Matlab code that shows how step by step PSO can be used in my case.

Comment: You can use [Optunity](http://docs.optunity.net), which has an easy API to perform particle swarm optimization in MATLAB. Examples are available [here](http://optunity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/wrappers/matlab.html).

Comment: is this using standard pso ?

Comment: Yes, Optunity exposes standard PSO.